# How to specify port in Port to port connection in php?

Tags: php, sockets, port

I am using shared hosting.If i want to make a socket connection to another server how can i specify which port from my machine to be used?And whats the best function in php for this purpose?In fsockopen() i am not able to specify my port.

Comment: "In fsockopen() i am not able to specify my port." Why not? Do you get an error when you do?

Comment: $fp = fsockopen("otherserver", 13, $errno, $errstr); i am not taking about port 13 i am connecting to but the port that is being used in my machine to make that connection.The port is required by the otherserver admins so that they can allow my connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to specify the source UDP port using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067579/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-source-udp-port-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't specify a different port using `fsockopen` then your shared hosting provider doesn't support it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that you can set the source port (and source binding IP) by using a stream context. See [Socket Context Options](http://php.net/context.socket).